# Outlook code review link opens wrong Visual Studio version

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, tfs

I have Visual Studio 2013 Premium and 2012 Premium installed. I get email notifications for code reviews in TFS. These notifications include a link to open the reviews, with display text "Open Changes and Comments in Visual Studio". The link location starts with

```
vstfs://codereview/...
```

When I click the links, the code reviews are opened in Visual Studio 2012.

How can I make Visual Studio 2013 handle the code review email links instead of Visual Studio 2012? I would like for them to be opened in Visual Studio 2013, instead.

Answer (score 8):

1. Open "default apps" on Window,
2. Select "Choose default apps by protocol" and scroll until you see "VSTFS"
3. Select "Microsoft Visual Studio Web Protocol Handler Selector" and test the options.

[image]

Comment: Each version of Visual Studio will have its own "Microsoft Visual Studio Web Protocol Handler Selector" in the list.  So when presented with multiple options (as shown in the screenshot), you just have to guess-and-check until you pick the correct one.

Comment: Thanks for that solution, this worked fine for me. As I only ever have two versions of VS installed (the recently installed newer one, and the older one I still keep until I'm shure I can uninstall) this guessing was easy: It's the other option in the list.

Answer (score 4):

Open your registry and modify the path to devenv.exe defined in the key `HKCR\vstfs\Shell\Open\Command\(Default)`

Comment: You must include a flag to devenv.exe, along with the input parameter (the URL for the resource you are trying to open).  For example, on my machine I changed the value to: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /TFSLink "%1"

Answer (score 1):

I repaired my Visual Studio 2013 installation and changed all of the filetypes associated with Visual Studio 2012 to be associated with 2013 in the Default Programs tool, and then restarted my PC. The problem is now resolved, but I don't know what fixed it; my guess is the 2013 repair.

Comment: Nope, it was the associations. There is a default application associated with "vstfs:" Protocal

Comment: I was not able to find any application or protocol in the default program list for "vstfs:" on windows 7.